# How to calc all height links in my treeview menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have un treeview menu (dropdown) and I would like set the height of one list on click.

Here is my code :

```
var btnCat = $('.blog-category__list'),
        sublistCat = $('.blog-category__sublist'),
        btnHeight = '69px',
        totalHeight = btnCat.outerHeight() + sublistCat.outerHeight();

    btnCat.click(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('triggerOpen')){
            $(this).removeClass('triggerOpen');
            $(this).css('height', btnHeight);
        } else{
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(this).addClass('triggerOpen');
            $(this).css('height', totalHeight);
        }
    });
```

It does not work well. It does not calculate the height of my li correctly.

Links will be added automatically in the menu, so I do not know how to know the height in advance.

Here is my html code :

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: You should probably calculate totalHeight within the click func.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet including the relevant HTML and CSS to demonstrate the issue as the code doesn't look wrong... or right.